# jQuery Validation for onChange or alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an interactive/editable table that does a number of things when a cell value is changed using `onChange="myfunction"`. The problem is that I need to have a few validations:

1. maxlength = 1
2. only letters ^[a-zA-Z]+$
3. cannot be blank...require = true

However I fear that due to using onChange I may not be able to achieve this.

Here is a working example of my table: http://jsfiddle.net/JEAkX/32/

Here is the jQuery validator code I am hoping to get to work:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "legalValue",
    function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test( value );
    },
    alert("Bad Value!")
);
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wholeTable").validate({
        rules: {
            cell: {
                legalValue: true,
                required: true,
                maxlength: 1
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to make this work given my current setup using onChange? If not what direction would you recommend taking to converting to a system that would allow for this validation.

If I stay with onChange do I need to great a global array to house the values of the table in the case that someone enters something incorrect and the value is reverted so the table doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

just had a look at your sources, I'm not sure I understand what is your problem, but your code has one mistake:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

not pushing you to solve the puzzle what's the difference is, I could say that path to script file is specifying using `src` attribute rather than using `scr`. After I changed that, when I enter "4" in any field, I get warning message about mistake etc. Also I can't enter few characters... So look like it works.. Was it the problem, or I didn't get your question?